# How to specify security constrains and security roles in spring boot [replacement of web.xml]?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I have a  case where I need to use the Application Server (Weblogic) and implement security. We are moving project from spring to spring boot
As Spring boot doesn't have any web.xml how do I write equivalent security constraint through java code.

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>rest-application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>xyz</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<Security-role>
<role-name>xyz></role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>abc</realm-name>
</login-config
```

Weblogic.xml will have below configuration

```
<security-role-assignment>
<role-name>xyz</role-name>
<principal-name>pars</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

Comment: You can follow this [doc][1]. 


  [1]: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/

Answer (score -1):

You may configure Spring Security using Java config with basic authentication.
make sure to add spring security dependency.

replace user/password and role and password algorithm you are using..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
          .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/public/paths").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic()

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```